Adjusting size of SVG fill in the legend box in QGIS
I would like to show the legend for a polygon layer that has three different classes of vegetation types. I expect that each legend item be represented by the entire SVG symbol.
Each of the vegetation types is represented by a different SVG symbol. The default in QGIS is to have the same size of the SVG symbol in the tiny legend rectangle as the size in the map.
The issue with this is that it results in only partially illustrating the symbol in the legend box. I can adjust the size of the symbol box (under Item properties, symbol) but not the symbol within the box. I would like to see one tree and one cluster of grass in the legend (i.e. the whole SVG symbol).
I run into similar issues with diagonal lines when they are too far apart to show up in the box. I have added the symbols manually (see below text in the final image) but I would like an automated method to do this.

Even more ridiculous scenario with standard symbol heights, where you cannot even see the symbol itself. I have added the full symbols manually below the text.


Which version of QGIS are you using ? or can you share your SVG symbols, I am not able to reproduce your problem with QGIS 3.28

I don't understand the question because I have had this problem with every single symbol since the start of my use of QGIS (~2014). I am currently using QGIS 3.36 (although I used 3.28 last year with the same problem). The symbol is from the "symbol" set in SVG and the size is set to 15. I need to bring it down to 5 for it to show up in the legend panel.

Back to this problem as it recurs often for me. The precise pictogram is the "landuse_deciduous" within the "symbol" set that is part of the standard list with QGIS.
